# Rails 3 validates_uniqueness_of with :scope generates invalid SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sqlite, validates-uniqueness-of

Have two models that record some monthly statistics and I'm trying to enforce a composite key constraint within the model using:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :entity_id, :scope => [:year, :month]
```

When trying to run a `.valid?` method on a record, I continually get an error as apparently ActiveRecord is generating improper SQL.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "FROM": syntax error: SELECT      FROM       "table"  WHERE     ("table"."entity_id" = 1) AND ("table"."year" = 2007) AND ("table"."month" = 6) LIMIT 1
```

Notice above that Rails isn't adding a * in the select statement and so SQLite correctly throws an error.

Any ideas if I've done something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
validates :entity_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:year, :month]}
```

you probably want

```
:presence => true
```